# Python: multiprocess workers, tracking tasks completed (missing completions)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The default `multiprocessing.Pool` code includes a counter to keep track of the number of tasks a worker has completed:

```
    completed += 1
logging.debug('worker exiting after %d tasks' % completed)
```

But going up from `range(12)` to `range(20)` a `pool.map` leads to errors in the counter (this appears to be unrelated to worker creation). I am not really clear on what's causing this either.

For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def ret_x(x): 
    return x
def inform():
    print('made a worker!')
pool  = mp.Pool(2, maxtasksperchild=2, initializer=inform)
res= pool.map(ret_x, range(8))
print(res)
```

Will work correctly giving:

```
made a worker!
made a worker!
worker exiting after 2 tasks
worker exiting after 2 tasks
made a worker!
worker exiting after 2 tasks
made a worker!
worker exiting after 2 tasks
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But changing the `range` to `20` doesn't show any additional workers being created or a total of 20 completed tasks, even though the finished range is returned in the expected list.

```
made a worker!
made a worker!
worker exiting after 2 tasks
worker exiting after 2 tasks
made a worker!
worker exiting after 2 tasks
made a worker!
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
worker exiting after 1 tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works that way because you are not defining explicitly "chunksize" in pool.map:

```
map(func, iterable[, chunksize])
```

> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it
>   submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size
>   of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive
>   integer

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

For 8 items, considering a len(pool)=2, chunksize will be 1 ( divmod(8,2*4)) so you see (8/1)/2 workers = 4 workers

```
workers = (len of items / chunksize) /  tasks per process
```

For 20 items, considering a len(pool)=2, chunksize will be 3 (divmode(20,2*4)) so you see something like (20/3)/2 = 3.3 workers

For 40...chunksize=5, workers= (40/5)/5 = 4 workers

If you want, you can set chunksize=1

```
res = pool.map(ret_x, range(40), 1)
```

And you will see (20/1)/2 = 10 workers

```
python mppp.py
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
made a worker!
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

So chunksize is like the amount of unit work for a process...or something like that.

How to calc chunksize: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c54def5947c/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l305

Comment: I see - I was looking at the worker run loop and assumed func ``try: result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))`` was running the `function` input to map but it's actually a chunk-sized generator for the task. That wasn't obvious.