# Need help trying to get a Python multiprocess pool working

Tags: python, pyodbc, python-multiprocessing

I have a database table I am reading rows from ( in this instance ~360k rows ) and placing the pyodbc.row objects into a list for later consumption then writing using this script.

```
from hashlib import sha1
import multiprocessing
import datetime, os
import pyodbc 
import math
import traceback, sys
source_rows = []
processors = 8

def split(a, n):
    k, m = len(a) / n, len(a) % n
    return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in xrange(n))

def sqn(*args):
    return sha1('}#EUCLID#{'.join([str(arg.upper().strip()) for arg in args]).encode()).hexdigest().upper()

def sDB_read():
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    #Initialize Source Database
    src_driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
    src_server='SCCMSV2SS010'
    src_database='STAGE'
    src_trusted_conn='yes'
    src_uid = 'myUserID'
    src_pwd = 'myPwd'
    if src_trusted_conn == 'yes':
        src_conn_str =  """Driver=""" + src_driver + """;Server=""" + src_server + """;Database=""" + src_database + """;Trusted_Connection=""" + src_trusted_conn + """;PacketSize=32767;"""
    else:
        src_conn_str =  """Driver=""" + src_driver + """;Server=""" + src_server + """;Database=""" + src_database + """;UID=""" + src_UID + """;PWD=""" + src_pwd + """;PacketSize=32767;"""
    sql = 'SELECT [AgentID]               ,[BootDevice00]              ,[BuildNumber00]              ,[BuildType00]              ,[Caption00]              ,[CodeSet00]              ,[CountryCode00]              ,[CSDVersion00]              ,[CurrentTimeZone00]              ,[Debug00]              ,[Description00]              ,[Distributed00]              ,[ForegroundApplicationBoost00]              ,[FreePhysicalMemory00]              ,[FreeSpaceInPagingFiles00]              ,[FreeVirtualMemory00]              ,[InstallDate00]              ,[InstanceKey]              ,[LastBootUpTime00]              ,[LocalDateTime00]              ,[Locale00]              ,[MachineID]              ,[Manufacturer00]              ,[MaxNumberOfProcesses00]              ,[MaxProcessMemorySize00]              ,[Name00]              ,[NumberOfLicensedUsers00]              ,[NumberOfProcesses00]              ,[NumberOfUsers00]              ,[OperatingSystemSKU00]              ,[Organization00]              ,[OSArchitecture00]              ,[OSLanguage00]              ,[OSProductSuite00]              ,[OSType00]              ,[OtherTypeDescription00]              ,[PlusProductID00]              ,[PlusVersionNumber00]              ,[Primary00]              ,[ProductType00]              ,[RegisteredUser00]              ,[RevisionID]              ,[rowversion]              ,[SerialNumber00]              ,[ServicePackMajorVersion00]              ,[ServicePackMinorVersion00]              ,[SizeStoredInPagingFiles00]              ,[Status00]              ,[SystemDevice00]              ,[SystemDirectory00]              ,[TimeKey]              ,[TotalSwapSpaceSize00]              ,[TotalVirtualMemorySize00]              ,[TotalVisibleMemorySize00]              ,[Version00]              ,[WindowsDirectory00]         FROM [STAGE].[dbo].[Operating_System_DATA]'
    src_db_conn = pyodbc.connect(src_conn_str)
    src_db_conn.autocommit = False
    src_db_cursor = src_db_conn.cursor()    
    src_db_cursor.execute( sql )    
    source_rows = [ {c[0]: v for (c, v) in zip(row.cursor_description, row)} for row in src_db_cursor.fetchall() ]
    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('\nWe Read ' + str(len(source_rows)) + ' rows in ' + str( t2 - t1 ))
    return source_rows

def tDB_write():    
    print('\nPOOL: Received ' + str(len( source_rows )) + ' rows to work on')
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    #Initialize Target Database    
    targ_driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
    targ_server='SCCMSV2SS010'
    targ_database='STAGE'
    targ_trusted_conn='yes'
    targ_uid = 'myUserID'
    targ_pwd = 'myPwd'
    if targ_trusted_conn == 'yes':
        targ_conn_str =  """Driver=""" + targ_driver + """;Server=""" + targ_server + """;Database=""" + targ_database + """;Trusted_Connection=""" + targ_trusted_conn + """;PacketSize=32767;"""
    else:
        targ_conn_str =  """Driver=""" + targ_driver + """;Server=""" + targ_server + """;Database=""" + targ_database + """;UID=""" + targ_UID + """;PWD=""" + targ_pwd + """;PacketSize=32767;"""
    targ_db_conn = pyodbc.connect(targ_conn_str)
    targ_db_conn.autocommit = False
    targ_db_cursor = targ_db_conn.cursor()           
    table = 'Operating_System_DATA_INSERT'    
    for sourceitems in source_rows:         
        for source_row in sourceitems:
            try:
                sql = ''                        
                #print( str( source_row ) )
                columns = ', '.join( source_row.keys() )            
                placeholders = ', '.join(['?'] * len( source_row ))
                obj = source_row.values()
                sql = "targ_db_cursor.execute('INSERT into {} ( {} ) VALUES ( {} )', {} )".format(table, columns, placeholders , obj )
                #print( sql )
                res = eval( sql )
            except Exception,e:
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)            
    targ_db_conn.commit()
    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('\nWe Wrote ' + str(len(source_rows)) + ' rows in ' + str( t2 - t1 ))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print( '\nStarting multiprocessing pool..' )
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool( processes = processors )
    source_rows = sDB_read()
    print( type(source_rows) )
    targetsize = len(source_rows)
    print( '\nProcessing ' + str(targetsize) + ' rows')
    chunksize = math.ceil(len(source_rows) / processors )    
    print( 'Splitting into ' + str(processors) + " chunks with " + str(chunksize) + ' rows each')
    source_rows = list(split( source_rows , processors ))
    write_pool_outputs = pool.map( tDB_write() , source_rows )
    print( '\nClosing multiprocessing pool..' )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

which provides the following output

```
c:\Python27>.\python27.exe .\multitest.py
Starting multiprocessing pool..
We Read 361554 rows in 0:00:14.064000
<type 'list'>
Processing 361554 rows
Splitting into 8 chunks with 45194.0 rows each
POOL: Received 8 rows to work on
```

I guess I am unclear on how to split/chunk the list up so each worker gets a equal share of the rows to work with. no matter if I try to split the list manually or just pass the unaltered one directly to the pool.map there is only one worker launched getting all the rows. Can some one educate me on the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be missing the chunksize in the pool.map call:

```
 map(func, iterable[, chunksize])
```

I gave an explanation of chunksize here: [Python: multiprocess workers, tracking tasks completed (missing completions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101232/python-multiprocess-workers-tracking-tasks-completed-missing-completions/28102116#28102116)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. +1 then

Comment: ty sir exactly the nudge i needed